# HTMLElement.getClientRects() sorted order

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I call `getClientRects()` on an `Element` in javascript (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects) at MDN), is there a defined order of the returned array?  Are the rects in the order of appearance of their respective child elements, as one would expect (at least in my mind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question.  From [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods):

> Return a ClientRectList object containing a list of ClientRect objects **in content order** describing the border boxes (including those with a height or width of zero)...

(Emphasis added)